# tvOS - playPause Gesture not working

Tags: swift, tvos, uitapgesturerecognizer, tvos10

PlayPause button is not responding. 
Here is my Code that I placed in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
playPauseTapGestureRegocnizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(playPauseTapped))
playPauseTapGestureRegocnizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.playPause.rawValue)]
view.addGestureRecognizer(playPauseTapGestureRegocnizer)
```

I tried placing it in multiple methods but it does not work. 
The weird thing is that when I change `playPause` with `menu` it works perfectly with the menu button.

Am I missing something?

Comment: With your code, it works for me. When I tap on the playPause button from Apple TV remote, the method `playPauseTapped()` is called. FYI, I'm using Xcode 9 and Apple TV 4K.

Comment: It does not work for me. how can I find out the reason why gesture is not responding? and why the menu button works and not the playPause button?

Comment: Did you try my solution below? @AymenHARRATH

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 4

PlayPause Gesture doesn't work on a real device.
Alternative solution is to listen to `UIPressesEvent`

```
override func pressesEnded(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?)
{
    for press in presses
    {
        if press.type == UIPress.PressType.playPause
        {
            // handle play pause action
            break
        }
        else
        {
            super.pressesEnded(presses, with: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RussellHarrower listen on `pressesEnded` in `viewDidLoad` and put this function on the view controller.

Comment: the issue is the xcode SwiftUI for tvOS did not give me an appDelegate. So Not sure where I am meant to put it. There is no global - `viewDidLoad` So i have to put it in very view.